# bootstrap-table: disable sorting on a row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-sortable

Is there any way to disable sorting on a specific row using the `bootstrap-table` library? The reason is my last row is a "Totals" row and I obviously want that to be the last row in every situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/11389/

It looks like this functionality is incorporated into this `bootstrap-sortable` [library](https://drvic10k.github.io/bootstrap-sortable/) by setting the `data-disable-sorting` attribute to `true` on the `<tr>` element you want to disable ([here](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable/issues/72)). Perhaps it's best to use this library on top of `bootstrap-table` if this isn't available in `bootstrap-table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. You can't disable sorting on any specific row (at the moment); however, you can add a footer row which locks it in to the bottom most row at all times. You just need to add `data-show-footer="true"` to the `<table>` element.

To add values to a column you need to add the `data-footer-formatter` attribute to the respective `<th>` element and set that equal to a javascript function, which can be as simple as `function myTotal(data){ return '100' }`.

You can also style the footer by adding the `data-footer-style` to the `<table>` element and, again, setting that equal to a javascript function.

See my answer here for a good, basic example: [Is it possible to fix <footer> in bootstraptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670909/is-it-possible-to-fix-footer-in-bootstraptable/42497942#42497942)